# Determine if a polygon feature is within a projection range in Openlayer 4

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers

This question comes following a previous one that I posted yesterday ([link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370387/how-to-show-single-geojson-file-features-when-changing-projection-with-openlayer)).

I have to show on a World Ocean Base map (projected as EPSG:3857) a number of areas. These are contained in a series of geojson files. Some of them are in the Antarctic. Hence I developed a switcher to change projection, from EPSG:3857 to Orthographic South.

The function is as follows

```
//=========================================
//=========================================  
// *****CHANGE OF PROJECTION*****
//=========================================
//=========================================

//CREATES A CIRCLE CANVAS TO CROP THE ORTHOGRAPHIC PROJECTION IN A PERFECT CIRCLE
var circle = new ol.geom.Circle([0, 0], 6370997);
var style = new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
  color: "black"
  })
});
var createCircle = function(e) {
    var vectorContext = e.vectorContext;
    e.context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
    vectorContext.setStyle(style);
    vectorContext.drawCircle(circle);
    e.context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
}
var viewProjSelect = document.getElementById('view-projection');

//FUNCTION TO MANAGE THE CHANGE OF PROJECTION
function updateViewProjection() {
        
        var newProj = viewProjSelect.value;

        if(newProj && newProj=="ORTHO-SOUTH") {
        var newView = new ol.View({
        projection: newProj,
        center: [0,-90],
        zoom: 0,
        minZoom: 0        
        });
        map.setView(newView);

          function updateLayer(layer) {
                if (layer.getSource) {
                    var source = layer.getSource();
                    if (source && source.getSource) {
                        // cluster source
                        source = source.getSource();
                    }
                    if (source && source.forEachFeature) {
                        source.forEachFeature(function(feature){
                            feature.getGeometry().transform(mercatorProjection, newProj);
                      });
                    }
                }
          } 

            map
            .on('postcompose', createCircle);
            map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer) { updateLayer(layer) });
  

        }
          else if (newProj && newProj=="EPSG:3857") {
            var newView = new ol.View({
            projection: newProj,
            center: [0,0],
            zoom: 2,
            minZoom: 1
            });
            map.setView(newView);
          function updateLayer(layer) {
                if (layer.getSource) {
                    var source = layer.getSource();
                    if (source && source.getSource) {
                        // cluster source
                        source = source.getSource();
                    }
                    if (source && source.forEachFeature) {

                        source.forEachFeature(function(feature){
                            
                            feature.getGeometry().transform("ORTHO-SOUTH", mercatorProjection);
                        });
                    }
                }
          } 
            map
            .un('postcompose', createCircle);
            map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer) { updateLayer(layer) });

        }
    };

//Handle change of projection

viewProjSelect.onchange = function() {
      updateViewProjection();
  };
```

The switcher works well if I use only features which boundaries are within the range of the Orthographic South projection. If I add areas outside that ranges (which are perfectly visible on the Mercator projection) they mess up the function (the author who helped me in developing the above function mentioned this problem in his answer). I searched on the forum and found that a possible solution is to use

```
ol.extent.containsExtent(extent2, extent1)
```

I tried the following solution, that doesn't work

```
var orthoExtent = [-6370997, -6370997, 6370997, 6370997];
var featExtent = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();

if (ol.extent.containsExtent(orthoExtent, featExtent)) {
  feature.getGeometry().transform(mercatorProjection, newProj);
}
else {//feature is not projected}
```

Any suggestion? My idea is, in order to avoid the mess up, to select only the features that are within the range of the OrthoGraphic projection and excluding the other ones (that are not visible anyway). If I change back to the mercator projection, then everything can be mapped again.

Comment: You would need to test by transforming a clone of the existing geometry `if (ol.extent.containsExtent(orthoExtent, feature.getGeometry().clone().transform(mercatorProjection, newProj)))` but as there are invalid regions inside the orthoExtent but outside its circle that might not be sufficient and it would be safer to keep a copy of everything in mercator.

Comment: I don't know very much about cloning, and probably it doesn't solve the problem. Some layers have sources that all fall within the Ortho projection and they are ok. Others have sources with single features that may fall within the Ortho projection or not (eg. some sources have areas around south Africa -> they could be projected and up to the Araabic Sea -> that cannot be projected). I wonder if at this point would be better to use the first version of my `updateViewProjection` function as from my previous question (see link above) and stick to a `.clear()` and `.refresh()` action.

Comment: As an update, I modified the function in  `if (source && source.forEachFeature) {source.forEachFeature(function(feature{feature.getGeometry().clone().transform(mercatorProjection, newProj);});source.clear();source.refresh();}` and it works again when all the layers are loaded. It doesn't work if I search in Mercator for a single feature (by applying a color to the feature and transparency to all the others) and then reproject the result. The feature disappears.